CMake sets “Generate Debug Symbols” - a Xcode build setting to wrong value

I’m trying to generate Xcode project file of some libraries with CMake.
I want to generate dSYM file in all build config type.
I set values in all my CMakelists.txt as below:
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g") set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "dwarf-with-dsym")
After CMake generate my xcodeproj file, I find out “Generate Debug Symbols” is set to true in Debug but set to false in Release build type
enter image description here
I only find it happened in one library, and other libraries worked perfectly.
Does anyone have a clue?
I found relevant question and tried, but not valid:
cmake-with-xcode-target-generate-debug-symbols-setting-ignored-for-release-conf

What I expect is as below image. Actually cmake works good with other library.
enter image description here

please show a [mre]

@AlanBirtles I finally solved it. The reason is the library includes *.c file, and I should add set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g") :(
